# Stack Apps updated site theme is ready for testing!

Tags: discussion, meta, design

As part of implementing the new unified themes across the network, we're gradually rolling out updated site themes for each site. As of today, we have enabled your updated site theme for testing.

If you can't see it right now, that's by design! This is a very early test implementation of your design and we need your help finding issues with it before we make it live for everyone permanently. So, keep in mind, there will be things that need fixing! We'll address those things as we can.

If you'd like to review it, here's how:

### How do I enable it?

[Click here](https://stackapps.com/users/preferences) and check the "Beta test new themes" option. This will turn on the new theme for all sites that have one in testing, including this one. *Here's [more info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314542/opt-in-to-beta-testing-new-themes) on how to opt in.* You can uncheck the box to revert to the older theme until the site is live for everyone. **Note, while turning it on is immediate, it will take a few minutes to revert to the old view - *but it will go through!***

### What type of feedback do we need?

#### On this post: Bugs related to this site's design elements

Please help us look for issues/bugs related to the theme design and how we have mapped the old theme to the new. This needs to be done within the [limits of the new unified theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes).

This could include colors of sections of the design or text, problems with JavaScript add-ons (if applicable), the logo or top banner appearance or other artwork.

You can also feel free to ask questions about the new layout if you're unsure how to navigate it.

#### On Meta Stack Exchange: General concerns about left nav or theming

There are some things that are definitely changing everywhere and can't really be adjusted on a per-site basis. A few of them include:

- Top banner is shorter in height, so some artwork has to be adjusted along with some logos.
- Left Navigation is active everywhere (but can be collapsed into a menu by visiting your site preferences - [instructions here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311237/284336)).
- Responsive layout is active, which lets the site adjust as browser widths change - no side scrolling (some pages haven't been updated, yet, though). For now, if you prefer the scrolling, you can disable this by clicking the "disable responsiveness" link in the footer.
- Many site elements including tags and voting arrows are standardized across the network.
- Link underlining is active. In an effort to make links more visible, they are now being underlined.

If you have concerns or issues regarding the left nav or the overall approach we are taking to theming, then [this Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness) is the right place for feedback.

As I mentioned earlier, there are some unique design elements like voting arrows and tags that are being standardized in this process. Keeping these custom elements makes our ability to maintain the sites too complex and, while we're very sad to see them go, we're in a difficult position of needing to make the site designs work together so that we can continue to address feature requests and bugs that will make your Q&A experience better. This is addressed in a [Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314799/why-we-initiated-the-latest-round-of-design-changes-and-the-role-of-meta) if you want more detail.

### What new themes?

If you're like, "What the heck are you talking about?", then you should read the Meta Stack Exchange post entitled [Rollout of new network site themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312365/rollout-of-new-network-site-themes) (and maybe the posts it links to for the full background). To follow along with the rollout of these new themes, go [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314979/rollout-of-responsive-design-site-themes-tracking-post).

### Thanks so much for your constructive feedback!

#### Oh, Who am I?

If you don't know me, I'm one of the [Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do?s=1%7C141.4591) here at Stack Exchange. I'm here to listen to your input and convey it to our Design team for responses and fixes to bugs. I'll do my best to respond to your concerns and explain whether changes we've made are bugs that can be changed or if they're by design and why.

Comment: Just want to reiterate that  **the Search input is too small** (Desktop browser) is a problem here too and rather annoying. ... [This MSE response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310911), item 1, lists it as "status-planned" but that was 5 months ago.

Answer (score 7):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

#### The [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) home pages are not giving new users the best impression.

Several [obsolete](/questions/tagged/obsolete), [placeholder](/questions/tagged/placeholder), **beta**, and **low-scoring** apps and scripts are placed prominently there.

This is closely related to [**this feature-request**](https://stackapps.com/questions/8027/can-we-change-the-stack-apps-homepage-tabs-to-not-show-questions-tagged-obsolet), but I propose more possible workarounds here.

I propose that in order for a post to get on the homepages (`https://stackapps.com/`, `https://stackapps.com/?tab=apps`, and `https://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts`), that **one or more of the following must be met:**

1. The post must have a score of, say, 2 or more.
2. The post must not be tagged [obsolete](/questions/tagged/obsolete) or [placeholder](/questions/tagged/placeholder).
3. If the post has [`<!-- version:  -->` metadata](https://stackapps.com/questions/7/how-to-list-your-application-library-wrapper-script-here), then the version must be 1.0 or greater.
4. Priority is given to posts that have a valid `<!-- thumbnail:  -->` image.

So this would effect the current homepage like:
(Click for larger view.)
      [image: Fix home page]

Comment: 1 and 2 would be fairly straightforward to implement. The query becomes [`app -placeholder -obsolete or library -placeholder -obsolete`](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app+-placeholder+-obsolete+or+library+-placeholder+-obsolete?sort=newest&pageSize=15) and knocks out about 50 apps.  Setting min score to 2 knocks out maybe 20 more.  3 and 4 are more complicated because they scan the body after the list already loaded.  The easiest thing would be to move items that pass 3 and 4 to the top of the list.

Comment: Thanks, @BrianNickel .  So, is this "status-planned"? :)  ... Note, also affects the `Scripts` tab.

Comment: Right now, the apps tab includes questions tagged either app or library.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

#### Can we get [**the home page**](https://stackapps.com/) to show all the tags for a post.

And also, ideally, the post's score:

EG, from:

> [image: Poor homepage]

To:

> [image: Better Homepage]