# Replace badge icons with rubber ducks

Tags: script, badges, design

The following userscript will replace the default badge icons with little rubber ducks

[image]

[image]

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        StackExchange, replace badge icons
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/*
// @exclude     *://api.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://blog.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://blog.stackoverflow.com/*
// @exclude     *://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://chat.stackoverflow.com/*
// @exclude     *://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://elections.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://openid.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://*/review
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle ( `

      /* change icons of badges */
      .badge1, .badge2, .badge3 {
         background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/9LE.svg") !important;
      }

` );
```

**Caveat:**

For a reason unknown to me, the ducks are cut off on some sites. For example they work fine on sites like

- tex.stackexchange.com
- codereview.stackexchange.com

but are cut off on

- stackapps.com
- meta.stackexchange.com

(these problems have been fixed in the answer https://stackapps.com/a/8117/54601 by Brock Adams)

Comment: See the revised answer.  Also, I added some metadata to your post; reference https://stackapps.com/a/8113/7653 and https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/script?sort=active.

Comment: @BrockAdams You are the best! Thanks a lot also for adding the meta information to my question, I was not aware of this possibility!

Comment: PS:  I'm amazed at how much having duckies everywhere makes SE sites a  little better.  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @BrockAdams I feel the effect too, I'm much more relaxed with low quality post etc. if there are lots of ducks in my field of view :) Maybe making this the default design would be much more effective then all this welcome wagon initiative thingy :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Source:**
See [GitHub: Stack Exchange, replace badge icons with duckies...](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/blob/master/Stack%20Exchange,%20replace%20badge%20icons%20with%20duckies.user.js) and **post bug reports and pull requests there.**

#### Install: <kbd>[Install from GitHub](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/raw/master/Stack%20Exchange%2C%20replace%20badge%20icons%20with%20duckies.user.js)</kbd>

Made some tweaks as follows:
June 01, 2019:

- Turned on styling for network-user pages.
- Fixed a race condition / GM_addStyle bug whereby the styles were not sticking for certain page loads.

November 16, 2018:

- Switched to proper SE image host because svgshare.com was crashing and "exceeding quota".
- Restored scripts to review paths, since they need duckies too.
- Moved the script to GitHub, where we can support it more effectively.

November 13, 2018:

- Fixed the icon cutoffs.
- Streamlined the `@exclude`s.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for your answer! Seems to work fine on the sites I have an account on.

Comment: What is the use of reputation if not to bounty it away? The only significant hurdle is to be able to comment everywhere and thanks to the association bonus this is covered. (fixed the missing accept, sorry :)

Comment: @samcarter, if you get more rep you can review, edit, etc. (hint, hint).

Comment: An alternative image with marmot, koala and duck can be found at https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3Ac5.png